Downtube Dent, should I worry about i? Trek Emonda ALR4
I bought a bike and probably the postman dented the downtube, should I try to return the bike or do you think dent like this is okay? The bike is TREK Emonda ALR4. Bought for half the price of new one. So the question is if I should return it, or just ask for some bigger sale on it, seller seems like a chill dude who would even told me I can return it to him.

The answers for this will be somewhat subjective. Being aluminum (I assume) it would probably function fine.  There can be issues with stress on aluminum, so that should be at least considered. However, in that location you would always notice it. My opinion (not an answer) is to return it for peace of mind and satisfaction in the condition and care of the bike you (will) have.

If I got a dent that size on my aluminum bike, I would keep riding it and use watchful waiting - keep checking that dent, look for cracks propagating, monitor changes in how the bike feels, especially under power, that sort of thing. Watchful waiting is active, and while you don't want to be worrying about it every second, you do need to maintain a background awareness.
On an ultralight aluminum frame, this would be much more concerning. The Emonda is probably relatively thick walls. On a steel frame, I believe it's possible to roll out a dent like this. If you do that to an aluminum frame, it will crack. Different material properties and all. Anyway, your downtube isn't round, so this wouldn't have been possible.
Anyway, what you decide to do with the frame is up to you. Hopefully this information helps.

Unless Trek has changed things recently, the Emonda is the ultralight model. The Domane and Madone are not as optimized for light weight.
